# WPF binding with a wcf service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, binding

How can i use this code in a wcf Service ?
When i used this code in my wpf project everythign works fine with
bindings. But when i want get this class out of my wcf service then i
get only the name of the class in my listbox and not the name of my 
pictures. i have used this code in my wcf service

```
 ImageFactory image = new ImageFactory();

    public ImageFactory GetData()
    {

        return image;
    }
```

someone knows how i can get to my picture data with a wcf service ?
did i something wrong in my wcf service ?

```
public class ImageFactory
    {
        private static Images _myactualdata = new Images();
        public static Images MyImages
        {
            get { return _myactualdata; }
        }

        public class Images : ObservableCollection<ImageData>
        {
            public Images()
            {
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"D:\WPF\Images\");
                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
                {
                    Add(new ImageData(f.FullName));
                }
            }
        }
        public class ImageData : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private String _sImageName = "";
            public ImageData(string sImageName)
            {
                ImageName = sImageName;
            }
            public String ImageName
            {
                get { return _sImageName; }
                set
                {
                    _sImageName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageName");
                }
            }
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String sProp)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(sProp));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```